# CRITICAL Error [38] : Unable to load raster

Tags: qgis, scp

[image]CRITICAL Error [38] : Unable to load raster

While dealing with Sentinel2 data, the above message occuring everytime even though I have entered all the files correctly and with no spaces in the directory.
How can I fix this problem?
I tried all methods and all type of Sentinel imageries but still same problem arises.

Comment: As you already [discovered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379723/error-38-unable-to-load-raster-trying-to-preprocess-satellite-images-from-sent), the issue is linked to the SCP plugin you are using. Have you tried contacting the provider?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works